# How many Domains can i add into developer account?

Tags: salesforce1-app, mydomain, custom-domain

I have already 3 domains, but I am not able to create another domain in salesforce and can't edit the published domain.

Answer (score 3):

A Published Domain cannot be edited. Instead, it must be deleted. After which a new domain can be created to replace the deleted domain. The only thing that can be edited is a Custom URL.

The [Salesforce Limits Quick Reference Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/) doesn't provide a definitive limit on the number of Domain names. It does however state that a Dev Account is only allowed one Site which would equate to 1 Domain name for the site. Elsewhere in [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_perm_license_about.htm&language=en_US), you'll discover that Developer Edition organizations contain two Site.com Publisher feature licenses and one Site.com Contributor feature license. However, Developer Edition organizations can’t publish sites.

From [Help - Domain Name Management](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_mgmt_overview.htm&language=en_US):

> Sites and domains can have a many-to-many relationship. Each domain can have up to 50 sites, and each site can be associated with up to 100 domains. For example, you might want to set up a single domain to host your Communities, Force.com, and Site.com sites. This simplifies your domain requirements. For Site.com sites, you might want to host them on the same domain as your Force.com sites because you can access Visualforce pages and have easier access to Apex code.
>
> There are also reasons why you would have a site on more than one
>   domain. For example, let’s say you have a parent company with two
>   distinct brands. Each brand has its own registered domain, but you
>   want them both to point to the parent website. Because you can have a
>   site exist on more than one domain, you can point both brand domains
>   to a single parent website.
>
> If you plan to host more than one site on
>   a domain, you’ll need to set up custom URLs for each site. Custom URLs
>   are the way to uniquely distinguish the sites within that domain.
>   Let’s say you have a domain called www.ourdomain.com and you want to
>   host two sites called siteone and sitetwo. You’ll need to create
>   custom URLs by associating ourdomain.com to each site using a custom
>   path. This will result in two custom URLs:
>   http://www.ourdomain.com/siteone and http://www.ourdomain.com/sitetwo.
>   When a web user accesses the domain using one of the URLs, the custom
>   path determines which site within the domain they see.

With all that said, considering that there are basically 3 different Community User licenses (assumes you exclude the HVCP license which can also be used) and that one normally uses a Sites Domain to host their Community, it makes a certain amount of sense that a Dev Org would be limited to a total of 3 Domains/Custom URLS. Also, a person can always get an additional Dev Org if they need more than this.

Comment: There is no option enabled for editing or deleting a domain. So how can i delete a domain and create a new one in that place?

Comment: Domains have to be registered with ICANN by Salesforce, so there's a cost associated with that. If you want a Dev Edition Domain Name edited or deleted by Salesforce, you'll need to file a case with support. If you have a EE or full version of SF where you have your own Domain Name, you can then edit or manage it yourself. Otherwise, it appears you can only edit Custom URLS.

Comment: Can i deploy a site in developer account?